# Blocked duplication way of Elements.xml

Tags: sharepoint-server, elements-xml

I'm trying to blocked duplication by elements.xml 
I read that an element must be indexed and i have to use the EnforceUniqueValues

So i added on my elements.xml

```
Indexed="TRUE"
EnforceUniqueValues="true"
```

But when i create a customer by way of that element i can still get a duplicate.
I would like to not do that on a Event Receiver.

Answer (score 0):

```
Required="TRUE" EnforceUniqueValues="TRUE" Indexed="TRUE" Sealed="TRUE"
```

I added that on the Elements.xml but also on the schema.xml